# fluentui/react ContexualMenu items styling

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

Im trying to style fluentui/react ContextualMenu component. So far i've been able to achieve the look I want by recursively modifying [IContextualMenuProps](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/contextualmenu#IContextualMenuProps) *items* prop - define **styles** for each [IContextualMenuItem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/contextualmenu#IContextualMenuItem) and repeating process for each submenu item.

```
import { ContextualMenu, IContextualMenuProps, IContextualMenuItem }  from '@fluentui/react';

export class StyledContextualMenu<IContextualMenuProps, {}>{

  setItemStyle = (items: IContextualMenuItem[])=> {
    return items.map(item => {
        item.itemProps.styles = {...};

        if (item.subMenuProps && item.subMenuProps.items)
          item.subMenuProps.items = this.setItemStyle(item.subMenuProps.items)

        return item;
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { items, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <ContextualMenu {...rest} items={this.setItemsStyle(items)}} />
  }
}
```

Is there a way to define styles for and it subcomponents at once instead of mutating items prop by adding a styles to each item?

Comment: I am trying to use contextualMenu. How did you solve it?
I am using class component as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to style components in Fluent UI React, and the choice depends on your needs and the Fluent UI flavor you're using. For example check out [this page on theming for Fluent UI Northstar](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.52.2/theming).

For a collection of items, I would think that either classes or variables on the main theme are appropriate.